# Trouble with a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying use create a sql query that uses a subquery, but I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. Ultimately, I want it to return a column that is a comma delimited string. The SELECT statment that gets the comma delimited string works well on its own, but when I try to use it within another SELECT Statement it give me an error. Here is the sub query:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + CAST(UpgradeID as varchar(20))
FROM [Table1]
SELECT @listStr
```

When I use that inside another select statement I get this error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

This is the entire query that's giving me the issue:

```
USE [DB1]

SELECT [UID]
      ,[PID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,(

        DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + CAST(UID as varchar(20))
        FROM [Table1]
        SELECT @listStr

      ) as result
  FROM [Table1]
```

Comment: Should your subquery return the same `result` on all the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + CAST(UpgradeID as varchar(20))
FROM [Table1]

USE [DB1]

SELECT
      [UID]
      ,[PID]
      ,[UserName]
      ,@listStr as result
FROM [Table1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable inside a subquery, but you can call it.
Also, I don't understand why you are calling the variable twice in the subquery.

Anyway, try the following:

```
USE [DB1]
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT [UID]
  ,[PID]
  ,[UserName]
  ,(

    SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + CAST(UID as varchar(20))
    FROM [Table1]

  ) as result
FROM [Table1]
```

Comment: Thank yo for the reply, it now gives the error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9 Incorrect syntax near '='."